# What is it about duplicate answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

Normally, our criteria for deletion is that something is *not an answer*. Spam, gibberish, comments, additional questions.

Yet there's the flag that shows up for duplicate answers, and some notion I spotted that late answers should get the bird somehow if duplicated.

We're supposed to vote on *content*, not *character*, so it certainly does not seem correct to downvote a technically accurate redundant answer.

We can't delete an answer, in general, unless it is voted below 0.

So this seems a bit of a catch-22. What is the intended workflow here?

I want to emphasize that this isn't only about late answers, though the answer might be to focus on those. If the team wants to say: "delete answers that are late+duplicate", then I merely want to ask for a cleaner workflow for that in the Late Answer queue. If the answer is that we want to strive to avoid redundant answers *in general*, then we need a fair way to deal with purely accidental (simultaneous) duplicates.

Comment: @SlyRaskal that's not the issue being discussed here. Fastest gun in the west is another issue. I believe OP is talking about _late_ duplicate answers.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, thanks for the clarification.  I'll remove my comment since it doesn't apply here. Cheers.

Answer (score 11):

> We're supposed to vote on content, not character,

That part I disagree with.

We're not supposed to vote on content, we're supposed to vote on **usefulness**.

A technically accurate redundant answer might be correct but if it's not useful it just clutters the question and prevent new answers with more insight from reaching viewers reducing the usefulness of the site.